# General Triangular Inequality for distance between subsets.

Tags: general-topology, inequality, metric-spaces, triangle-inequality

Suppose we have $A$ and $B$ as subsets of a metric space $(E, d)$. Is it true that for any subset $C$ of $E$, $d(A, B) \leq  d(A, C) + d(C, B)$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

As a counterexample:

let $E =\mathbb{R}$.

let $A = ]-\infty, 1]$ and $B = [3, \infty[$. Take $C = [0, 4]$. It is evident that $d(A, C) + d(C, B) = 0 < d(A, B) = 2$